# Transitive save

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a question about hibernate.

I want to save a small graph of detached objects :

```
session.save(new City(1));

Peron p = new Person(new City(1), new Street(2));
session.save(p);
```

Hibernate told me that city is transient but I do :

```
session.refresh(city);
session.refresh(street);
session.update(p);
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either do something like this:

```
City city = new City(1);
session.save(city);

Street street = new Street(2);
session.save(street);

Peron p = new Person(city, street);
session.save(p);

session.flush();
```

Or setup cascading to cascade the `save` operation. For example, with annotations:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) // or ALL to cascade all operations
    private City city;

    // ...
}
```

And then the code becomes:

```
City city = new City(1);
Street street = new Street(2);
Person p = new Person(city, street);
session.save(p);
session.flush();
```

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification

  - Section 3.2.1 "Persisting an Entity Instance"
  - Section 9.1.22 "ManyToOne Annotation"
- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [10.11. Transitive persistence](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive)
- Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide

  - [2.4.7. Cascade](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-cascade) (extensions of the JPA specification)

Comment: Thanks for your response, you know if we delete a Person, the delete will be cascaded no ?

Comment: @Simo If you configure Hibernate to cascade the delete operation too, yes it will.